# Gitlab omnibus - how to browse code in web

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab

I am new to gitlab and git, hence apologies if this is a naive question. I am planning to install gitlab omnibus in my amazon ec2 server. Assuming that there is an elastic IP for the server, will it be possible to browse the code / doc committed there through a desktop or mobile web browser?
Idea is to have a private repository which is accessible (using a userid/password) from the mobile web browser.

Comment: I googled Gitlab, and since it says you can host it yourself I'm going to say the answer here is "yes" ?

Comment: Hi scrowler, 
Thanks. In that case, I was wondering how the UI looks like - is it just like accessing static files hosted in your http server, or there is Web application available inside gitlab omnibus which gives similar user experience like GitLab browser access for repositories hosted in GitLab cloud.

Comment: You'd have to try it (free?) but I'd say it's going to be the same as the cloud version